# failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory

Tags: nagios

The check_nrpe script can resolve the custom monitor to the host

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 172.31.3.90 -c pinger
```

In the Nagios Dashboard it throws an error

```
failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory
```

Networking and other dependencies work fine and the define command and service seem fine as well

```
define command {
        command_name    pinger
        command_line    check_nrpe!pinger
}

define service {
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       ci3
        service_description             pinger
        check_command                   pinger
}
```

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iDaI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The check_nrpe command must be added to the nagios server in the file

```
/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
```

The entry references the program check_nrpe

```
define command {
       command_name                             check_nrpe
       command_line                             /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTNAME$ -c pinger
}
```

now the service is collecting data and can be verified in the [Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEv9e.png)